# connecting java applet with remote(?) mysql server

Tags: mysql, applet

I have a mysql database and an applet in some free hosting site. The applet needs to access that mysql database. How do I do that ? Is it possible to remote access mysql database from an applet? how ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The applet will execute on the client browser. 
Its doubtful/unlikely that your free hosting provider allows remote mysql connections. 
So your best bet would be some sort of [HTTP web service](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_service).

If you can use Java on the server then check out [CXF](http://cxf.apache.org/). 
If you can only use PHP then things are tougher but look at [NuSOAP](http://sourceforge.net/projects/nusoap/).

On your applet you can use CXF to consume the service.

Comment: can you please give me some link ? I am not sure what you are talking about... :(